# Filter object properties (keys) keeping typings

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a function to filter (include | exclude) an object properties.
JS Function is working fine but I can't figure out how to type it correctly.
Here's what I've attempted so far:

```
// filter object keys
export const filterObjKeys = <T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  includeKeys: K[] = [],
  excludeKeys: K[] = [],
): T => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) =>
      includeKeys?.length > 0 ? includeKeys.includes(k) : !excludeKeys.includes(k),
    ),
  ) as Omit<T, typeof excludeKeys>;
};
```

This is my desired result (it works but types on results are wrong, they remain the same of the complete interface):

```
interface Student {
  firtsName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  class: number;
}

const student: Student = {
  firtsName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  email: 'a@b.com',
  class: 3,
};

const filteredStudentInc = filterObjKeys(student, ['firtsName', 'lastName']);
// {firtsName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}

const filteredStudentExc = filterObjKeys(student, [], ['email'])
// {firtsName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', class: 3}
```

Comment: You'd better make it overloads as they are not used both at once

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6z7rw) work for you?

Comment: @wonderflame filteredStudentInc is ok but filteredStudentExc is not working

Comment: @Dimava yes sure I'll make overloads, but I've the same question. Can you give me an example of how to type both?

Comment: @crivella check [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPKyem) one

Comment: @wonderflame it works perfectly, please add as answer. Can you explain me how your "Prettify" works and why I have to explicit K[number] and not only K?

Comment: sure, will do in the answer

Comment: @wonderflame I've tried a simplified version of your code but I still have this error:

export const filterObjKeys = <T extends object, K extends (keyof T & string)[]>(obj: T, excludeKeys: K): Prettify<Omit<T, K[number]>> => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => excludeKeys.includes(k)))
};

Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof T & string'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof T'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Comment: I didn't cover the implementation part. Only the typings, you will need to have some type assertions anyway

Comment: @crivella should I proceed with writing the answer?

Comment: @wonderflame yes sure! Please write the implementation part, too, and split the code in two different functions (excludeObjKeys and pickObjKeys): I think it will be easier to understand also for future readers.

Comment: @crivella What happens if a key is part of both include and exclude, you want to give priority to include, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's update our constraints.
`T extends {}` doesn't mean that `T` is a non-primitive type. The correct option would be `object`:

```
// true
type Case1 = number extends {} ? true : false
// false
type Case2 = number extends object ? true : false
```

For the keys probably you will need only string keys, thus let's extract only string keys by either intersecting `keyof T & string` or using [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) `Extract<keyof T, string>`

Now, let's implement the `pickObjKeys`:

```
export const pickObjKeys = <T extends object, K extends keyof T & string>(
  obj: T,
  keys: K[],
): Pick<T, K> => {
  return Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key) => [key, obj[key]])) as Pick<T, K>;
};
```

I've simplified the implementation's logic, now instead of `Object.entries` we generate entries using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the passed keys. Note that unfortunately, there will be no way to make the whole implementation fully type-safe, thus we will need to use assertion to get rid of the error. To actually pick the fields we use the built-in [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) utility type.

Testing:

```
// const filteredStudentInc: Pick<Student, "firtsName" | "lastName">
const filteredStudentInc = pickObjKeys(student, ['firtsName', 'lastName']);
```

It looks correct, but if we want to see how the type exactly looks we will need some utility that will make the result types more readable:

[Prettify](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/prettify.d.ts?plain=1#L15) - Accepts a type and returns its simplified version for better readability. Transforms interface to type, simplifies intersections

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R
  ? {
      [K in keyof R]: R[K];
    }
  : never;
```

`Prettify` works because we redeclare the type and remap its fields, which results in more literal types.

Testing:

```
const pickObjKeys = <T extends object, K extends keyof T & string>(
  obj: T,
  keys: K[],
): Prettify<Pick<T, K>> => {
  return Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key) => [key, obj[key]])) as Prettify<
    Pick<T, K>
  >;
};

// const filteredStudentInc: {
//   firtsName: string;
//   lastName: string;
// }
const filteredStudentInc = pickObjKeys(student, ['firtsName', 'lastName']);
```

Now, let's jump to the `excludeObjKeys`:

```
const excludeObjKeys = <T extends object, K extends keyof T & string>(
  obj: T,
  keys: K[],
): Prettify<Omit<T, K>> => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(obj).reduce<[string, unknown][]>((acc, key) => {
      if (!keys.includes(key as K)) acc.push([key, obj[key as K]]);

      return acc;
    }, []),
  ) as Prettify<Omit<T, K>>;
};
```

The logic here is a bit more complex, however, I've tried to optimize it as I could. We get the keys using `Object.keys` and using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) we both generate entries and filter out excluded properties. And to remove the properties from the type we need the built-in [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility type.

Testing:

```
// const filteredStudentExc: {
//   firtsName: string;
//   lastName: string;
// }
const filteredStudentExc = excludeObjKeys(student, ['email', 'class']);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ts=5.0.4#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-WOXHEH2yAhc6y6vHkKelSglBGizc5g4Bg4ILsGVbVGA6hbHvbhEGUC7Pf7g+HUAA5AApeShygfgtJzsGd3w-AAReQIAAoQlz2Fd1A-PYAAE3BmaxFmg7gt1oHcAGYykBDgOAAemIp8VzrCBqFvNtgAASUoSx1EEUiUxIZdVwvdcxxIsiU2wnc9wPI9WIMM97C7CFKOoy81gYywCAcDo4R8PI7DvKIoBED9YJXADPwEj97h0M95AhCAZgheRsjySTpJoq95LqIjeNtViU2fXsQLXBdXJTIDpzfHyN1csSbHPOyWCohy1mWUgFMIcEoRhFSETU2TNO03SIX0j9DOM09wrMiyrJsyL5Ri4A4ssZygA)

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Just a question: why if I call excludeObjKeys(obj, ['key1']) typescript is ok but if I declare ['key1'] previously (let test = ['key1']) and pass "test" as argument typescript say error? (I've tried typing let test: (keyof MyInt & string)[] , but in that case I loose typings in result)

Comment: Because `test` will have a type of `string[]`, which is the default behavior of the compiler to widen the non-primitive types.